# How to prevent managed android devices from factory reset

Tags: enterprise, mdm

We're currently using the Android Management API to manage our Android devices. ​If anyone try to factory reset the device than enable FRP policy activate but the newborn are so smart they byepass the FRP and than we are not able to manage these devices. Is there any solution to protect these devices from factory reset.

Anyone having solution for this